# How to implement storage permission in android 11. Can someone share an example implemented in java

Tags: java, android, permissions, storage, android-11

```
Intent chooserIntent = null;
       try {
           StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
           StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
   
           List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
           Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                   MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
           Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
           takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
           intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, pickIntent);
           intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);
   
           if (intentList.size() > 0) {
               chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1),
                       "Select photo !");
               chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
           }
           return chooserIntent;
       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Here I am getting intent size 0 after setting the version to 30 , but in previous version it was working fine.

Comment: After adding the below code in the manifest I am able to select images from the gallery


<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" />
    </intent>
</queries>

Comment: For what this strict mode stuff? You do not need queries in order to select images.

Comment: What should your code do? What does it have to do with the title of your post?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

add permission

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

add this line manifest file application tag

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

take those variable in your activity

```
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
```

in Activity onCreateView method

```
int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                MainActivity.this,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }

    else {

       //write code for permission granted 
    }
```

Comment: Strange code. One does not need those permissions in order to use ACTION_PICK or ACTION_GET_CONTENT. So what is it that you have in mind?